# read and write the same text file

Tags: python, file

What I want to do:

- Open a text file
- Read the content
- Make some changes on it
- Write it back to the file

Now the modified text should only has the modified content but not the initial content.

Can we implement this by only set the mode parameter with `open()` function ?

If Yes, What the parameter should be?
if No, Can we implement this by only one with statement?

I implement this with 2 with statements as the following

```
replace_pattern = re.compile(r"<.+?>",re.DOTALL)

def text_process(file):

    with open(file,'r') as f:
        text = f.read()

    with open(file,'w') as f:
        f.write(replace_pattern.sub('',text))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to replace the text in a file with the 'fixed' version, you have to either re-open the file, or open it in `r+` (read + write) mode and truncate before writing:

```
with open(file,'r+') as f:
    text = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.write(replace_pattern.sub('',text))
```

If you do not truncate the file first, then you run the risk of writing out *too few new bytes*. You read `foo bar baz` and write out `foo spam`, then your file ends up as `foo spambaz` as the *old* data is not removed and was longer.

Comment: `r+` mode also allows for "direct" writing to the file, using `f.seek(some_position)` then `f.write(some_bytes)` doesn't it?

Comment: @heltonbiker: Added why you want to truncate first.

Comment: You need to seek to 0 first, or you will start writing to the position where the old text ended (with the beginning being empty).

Comment: @poke: right, though that could be platform dependent. Updated to be certain.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It is platform dependent what the unused space is filled with but not that the stream pointer won’t change with truncate. So you definitely want to use seek.

Comment: From what I understood, the solution to the OP's task is just a special case of more general moneuvers made possible by the conscious use of `seek`, `read`, `write` and `truncate`. Some subtle variation on intended result would necessarily call for some different solution using these same methods.

Comment: this question is also solved here
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.lang.python/x9ciu2ws3Tg